# SwiftUI navigation: how to Pop current view when navigate to new view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigation

I am trying to pop current view (or multiple views) when navigate to new view in SwiftUI. But ther is bug in iOS 14,15. for exmple, i naigate like this:

[Login view] -> [register view step 1] -> [register view step 2]

then i need to pop the register views and navigate to verification view like this:

[Login view] -> [verification view]

When i try to do this in iOS 14, 15 this happening:
Register views popp, Verification view push and pop immediately and go back to Login view!

Here is my code:

```
class StateManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var login: Bool = false
    @Published var register_step_1: Bool = false
    @Published var register_step_2: Bool = false
    @Published var verification_page: Bool = false
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var stateManager: StateManager

    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            NavigationStack {
                SplashViewContent()
            }
            
        } else {
            NavigationView {
                SplashViewContent()
            }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)

        }
    }
}
```

```
struct LoginView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var stateManager: StateManager
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Login").font(.title)
           
            Button(action: {
                stateManager.register_step_1 = true
            }, label: {
                Text("Navigate to Register")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct Register1View: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var stateManager: StateManager
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Register 1").font(.title)
           
            Button(action: {
                stateManager.register_step_2 = true
            }, label: {
                Text("Navigate to Register 2")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct Register2View: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var stateManager: StateManager
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Register 2").font(.title)
           
            Button(action: {
                stateManager.register_step_2 = false
                stateManager.register_step_1 = false
                stateManager.verification_page = true
            }, label: {
                Text("Navigate to Verification view")
            })
        }
    }
}
```